# Prove that inverses in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ are unique.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be any natural number and let $a$ be an integer where $\gcd(a,m) = 1$. We know that an inverse of $[a]$ exists in $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$. Prove that this inverse is unique, i.e. there is exactly one congruence class $[b]$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ such that $[a][b] = [1]$.

Thanks for anybody who can help me solve this question!

Comment: Hi, Michael: feel free to accept an answer (one per question) if it's been helpful. To accept an answer, simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer. You get two  reputation points for each accepted answer. You may upvote as many answers as you'd like. And accepting/upvoting is one way to let users know that you find answers, and the site, helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $ab_1\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ and $ab_2\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. then by subtraction $a(b_1-b_2)\equiv 0\pmod{m}$, that is, $m$ divides $a(b_1-b_2)$.

Since $ab_1\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, it follows that $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime. If proof of this is needed, note that if $ab_1=1+km$, and $d$ divides $a$ and $m$. hus $d$ divides $ab_1-km$, meaning that $d$ divides $1$.

Since $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime, if $m$ divides $a(b_1-b_2)$, then $m$ must divide $b_1-b_2$. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $[b]$ and $[b']$ are inverses of $[a]$. Then $$[a]\cdot [b] = [1] = [a]\cdot [b'].$$ Multiplication with $[b]$ gives $$\underbrace{[b]\cdot [a]}_{=[1]}\cdot [b] = \underbrace{[b]\cdot [a]}_{=[1]}\cdot [b'],$$ so $[b] = [b']$.